# Using MTAudioProcessingTap for FFT on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, fft, core-audio

So I have tried to read everything I can about FFT with the the Accelerate.framework and got an example working that works with MTAudioProcessingTap but I feel like I am doing something wrong and my plotted points shouldn't look like this.

[image: plotted points from FFT]

```
#import "AudioTap.h"


#pragma mark - TapContext

typedef struct TapContext {
    void *audioTap;
    Float64 sampleRate;
    UInt32 numSamples;
    FFTSetup fftSetup;
    COMPLEX_SPLIT split;
    float *window;
    float *inReal;

} TapContext;


#pragma mark - AudioTap Callbacks

static void TapInit(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, void *clientInfo, void **tapStorageOut)
{
    TapContext *context = calloc(1, sizeof(TapContext));
    context->audioTap = clientInfo;
    context->sampleRate = NAN;
    context->numSamples = 4096;

    vDSP_Length log2n = log2f((float)context->numSamples);

    int nOver2 = context->numSamples/2;

    context->inReal = (float *) malloc(context->numSamples * sizeof(float));
    context->split.realp = (float *) malloc(nOver2*sizeof(float));
    context->split.imagp = (float *) malloc(nOver2*sizeof(float));

    context->fftSetup = vDSP_create_fftsetup(log2n, FFT_RADIX2);

    context->window = (float *) malloc(context->numSamples * sizeof(float));
    vDSP_hann_window(context->window, context->numSamples, vDSP_HANN_DENORM);



    *tapStorageOut = context;
}

static void TapPrepare(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, CMItemCount numberFrames, const AudioStreamBasicDescription *format)
{
    TapContext *context = (TapContext *)MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap);
    context->sampleRate = format->mSampleRate;

    if (format->mFormatFlags & kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved) {
        NSLog(@"is Non Interleaved");
    }

    if (format->mFormatFlags & kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger) {
        NSLog(@"dealing with integers");
    }
}


static  void TapProcess(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, CMItemCount numberFrames, MTAudioProcessingTapFlags flags,
                        AudioBufferList *bufferListInOut, CMItemCount *numberFramesOut, MTAudioProcessingTapFlags *flagsOut)
{


    OSStatus status;

    status = MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio(tap, numberFrames, bufferListInOut, flagsOut, NULL, numberFramesOut);
    if (status != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio: %d", (int)status);
        return;
    }

    //UInt32 bufferCount = bufferListInOut->mNumberBuffers;

    AudioBuffer *firstBuffer = &bufferListInOut->mBuffers[1];

    float *bufferData = firstBuffer->mData;
    //UInt32 dataSize = firstBuffer->mDataByteSize;
    //printf(": %li", dataSize);





    TapContext *context = (TapContext *)MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap);

    vDSP_vmul(bufferData, 1, context->window, 1, context->inReal, 1, context->numSamples);

    vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX *)context->inReal, 2, &context->split, 1, context->numSamples/2);


    vDSP_Length log2n = log2f((float)context->numSamples);
    vDSP_fft_zrip(context->fftSetup, &context->split, 1, log2n, FFT_FORWARD);
    context->split.imagp[0] = 0.0;

    UInt32 i;


    NSMutableArray *outData = [NSMutableArray array];

    [outData addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0]];
    for( i = 1; i < context->numSamples; i++) {
        float power = context->split.realp[i] * context->split.realp[i] + context->split.imagp[i] * context->split.imagp[i];
        //amp[i] = sqrtf(power);

        [outData addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:sqrtf(power)]];
    }


    AudioTap *audioTap = (__bridge AudioTap *)context->audioTap;
    [audioTap updateSpectrum:outData];

}

static void TapUnprepare(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap)
{

}

static void TapFinalize(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap)
{
    TapContext *context = (TapContext *)MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap);

    free(context->split.realp);
    free(context->split.imagp);
    free(context->inReal);
    free(context->window);

    context->fftSetup = nil;
    context->audioTap = nil;
    free(context);
}






#pragma mark - AudioTap Implementation


@implementation AudioTap

- (id)initWithTrack:(AVAssetTrack *)track frameSize:(UInt32)frameSize
{

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        _assetTrack = track;
        _frameSize = frameSize;

        [self setupAudioTap];

    }
    return self;

}

- (void)setupAudioTap
{
    //MTAudioProcessingTap
    MTAudioProcessingTapCallbacks callbacks;

    callbacks.version = kMTAudioProcessingTapCallbacksVersion_0;

    callbacks.init = TapInit;
    callbacks.prepare = TapPrepare;
    callbacks.process = TapProcess;
    callbacks.unprepare = TapUnprepare;
    callbacks.finalize = TapFinalize;
    callbacks.clientInfo = (__bridge void *)self;

    MTAudioProcessingTapRef tapRef;
    OSStatus err = MTAudioProcessingTapCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &callbacks,
                                              kMTAudioProcessingTapCreationFlag_PostEffects, &tapRef);

    if (err || !tapRef) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to create AudioProcessingTap.");
        return;
    }

    //Audio Mix
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *inputParams = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters
                                                     audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:_assetTrack];

    inputParams.audioTapProcessor = tapRef;

    AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
    audioMix.inputParameters = @[inputParams];
    _audioMix = audioMix;
}



- (void)updateSpectrum:(NSArray *)data
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Forward left and right channel volume to delegate.
            if (_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(updateSpectrum:)]) {
                [_delegate updateSpectrum:data];
            }
        });
    }
}

@end
```

I was reading that the audioBuffer->mData property could be something else other then a float (ie SInt32, etc?), If that is true how to make sure i convert it properly before attempting the FFT on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plot length and the real FFT magnitude result length (2^log2n)/2 are not the same.

Comment: so I am creating an NSArray length that is wrong? Should my length be (2^log2n)/2 ? Could you give me a bit of explanation, This is all stil l a bit new to me.

Comment: Plus am I even doing this right if I want to visualize magnitude of the full range of frequencies from the music that is playing?

Comment: Actually I finally got some clarification on FFT in general on how frequencies get plotted. Now I just need to put more weight onto the higher frequencies.

Comment: @DevGoose, did you finally get the completed solution? If yes, could you please post the answer. Do you have the final code available somewhere?